# How to load the data without text qualifiers dynamically from a file using PIG/HIVE/HBASE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

My csv file contain 150 columns!! It contain `""` as text qualifiers. how can i remove quotes(`""`) using `pig/hive/hbase dynamic` script? similarly I have multiple files(50 csv files with different columns). How can i remove these `""` from different files?

I tried with below pig script for 2 columns in a file:

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs://<hostname>:<port>/user/test/input.csv' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'"(.*)","(.*)"')) AS (id:int,name:chararray);
STORE B INTO '/user/test/output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

**input.txt**

```
"123","456","789"
"abc","def","ghi"
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'\\"','') AS line1;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line1,'\\,',3));
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0,$1,$2;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(123,456,789)
(abc,def,ghi)
```

In your case you can change the above 3rd line to `STRSPLIT(line1,'\\,',150)`, where 150 is the total number of columns and you can access all the values by `$0,$1...$149`